# How to access private blob container inside pipeline job - Azure SDKv2?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk-python

I have this example taken from the official documentation (the one you see below).

```
from azure.ai.ml import command, Input, MLClient, UserIdentityConfiguration, ManagedIdentityConfiguration
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes, InputOutputModes
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# Set your subscription, resource group and workspace name:
subscription_id = "<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"
resource_group = "<RESOURCE_GROUP>"
workspace = "<AML_WORKSPACE_NAME>"

# connect to the AzureML workspace
ml_client = MLClient(
    DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)

# ==============================================================
# You can set the identity you want to use in a job to access the data. Options include:
# identity = UserIdentityConfiguration() # Use the user's identity
# identity = ManagedIdentityConfiguration() # Use the compute target managed identity
# ==============================================================
# This example accesses public data, so we don't need an identity.
# You also set identity to None if you use a credential-based datastore
identity = None

# Set the input for the job:
inputs = {
    "input_data": Input(type=data_type, path=path, mode=mode)
}

# This command job uses the head Linux command to print the first 10 lines of the file
job = command(
    command="head ${{inputs.input_data}}",
    inputs=inputs,
    environment="azureml://registries/azureml/environments/sklearn-1.1/versions/4",
    compute="cpu-cluster",
    identity=identity,
)

# Submit the command
ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(job)
```

The above code is from the Azure documentation.

I have a case in which the below Input is fed to a pipeline job. However, my use case requires that the container is private.

Therefore, my issue is that the container name is private, so I cannot access it like in the tutorial above.

I understand that I need to assign some permissions, I already have a managed identity on the cluster on which the code runs, which has the following permissions:

1. Owner and Contributor of the storage account which includes the storage blob container.
2. Owner and Contributor of the machine learning workspace.

I have a custom input which looks like:

```
    Input(
                type="uri_folder",
                # Here is the problem, cannot access it in a job.     
                path="wasbs://container_name@storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/",
                mode="ro_mount"
          ),
```

What should I do in order to be able to access, like in the example input below, data inside a private container inside my job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I had to add this role to the Managed Identity:

```
Storage Blob Data Contributor
```

(because I read and write to that Private Blob inside the Storage Account)